# Check the position of the given values inside the arraylist in android

Tags: android, arraylist

I just wanna ask for help in getting the index of the given values inside the arraylist. For example I have 
**arraylist brand contains {"a","b","c","d","e"}** 
and another 
**arraylist chosen contains {"a","c","e"}** 
how will I know the index of the values in arraylist chosen in arraylist brands? Thank you.

I have tried

```
for (int j=0; j<checkSelected.length; j++) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Brands.size(); i++) 
        {
            checkSelected[i] = true;

        }
    }
```

What I am trying to do is to get the index of my values in my chosen arraylist to to the arraylist brand so that will be easy to set the value of that index in true in the other arraylist. But in my code above it only gets the size of the of my arraylist.

Comment: :D what you are asking here? Title is clear but description made me confused..

Comment: Your code snippet acctually confuses me more ;-) Maybe you should state what you are exactly trying to achieve. Does one of the answers help you and if not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate over `chosen` and get every index.

```
for(String chosenElement : chosen) {
    int index = brand.indexOf(chosenElement);
    // Do something with the index
}
```

This works not only with lists of `String` but with every type where `equals()` is properly overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the 'chosen' list and use [indexOf(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) for each object.

Answer (score 0):

there are methodes indexOf and contains. Check them out